# VS Express 2015 Win10 Application - ifstream does not open file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

fstream, ifstream and ofstream in VS Express 2015 C++ simply does not work for me. I tried to open a file in MingGW which of course worked, but in VS Studio it does not want to open the file with the given location. I also put the file "Artikel.txt" in the project root, but it did not make a difference.
Trying with errno to detect the error, failed. I could not get the error message in the output as well.

```
void App1::MainPage::initArtikel()
{
    ifstream file;
    file.open(L"C:\\Users\\...\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\Projects\\App1\\Artikel.txt");
    string zeile;
    Artikel neuerArtikel;
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"Artikel.csv wird geöffnet...");
        while (getline(file, zeile))
        {
            size_t pos = 0;
            string token;

            //Erste Spalte "Name"
            pos = zeile.find(CSV_DELIM); 
            token = zeile.substr(0, pos);
            neuerArtikel.Name = stops(token);
            zeile.erase(0, pos + 1);

            //Zweite Spalte "Preis"
            pos = zeile.find(CSV_DELIM);
            token = zeile.substr(0, pos);
            neuerArtikel.Preis = stod(token);
            zeile.erase(0, pos + 1);

            sortiment.push_back(neuerArtikel);
        }
        //file.close();
    }
    else
    {
        OutputDebugStringA(strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

Comment: Try opening it providing wide string path. Maybe path contains non-Unicode symbols.

Comment: Check the error code from `errno`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add relevant information. Comments are not suitable for status updates.

Answer (score 0):

In my case `OutputDebugStringA(strerror(errno));` delivers:

> 'Permission denied'

If I use `file.open(Artikel.csv");` then I get the following error:

> 'No such file or directory'

Actually putting the file "Artikel.csv" in location:

> C:\Users\ ...\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\Debug\App1\AppX

gave me the output:

> 'Artikel.csv wird geöffnet'